# antagonistic movements: Dips Into Chin ups or Overhead press into Chin upss

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, movements

Post inspired by [What are supersets and are they even worth doing?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPAJndw2BiQ)

The video has sources suggesting that antagonistc **supersets** are superior to normal sets in terms of muscle growth and strength gain.

To maximize the effect should I superset chin ups with ring dips or with overhead pressing?

Source of my confusion: Both dips and overhead presses are vertical patterns that work the front of the torso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chin ups are a pulling movement where your hands are overhead, so the opposing movement would be a pressing movement with your hands overhead, i.e. overhead press.